# ruby not understanding this behavior when iterating through array

Tags: ruby

I am having a problem with the following array iteration. I'd like to create an array `jt` with the phrase "food" and "drink" as can be seen from the output from first command which is constructed from an item that has two `global_tags` with each tag having a phrase that is, in this case, `food` or `drink`. I'm not sure why I get the two embedded arrays as seen in the last line.

```
1.9.3p392 :043 > m.global_tags.map { |t| puts t.tag.phrase }
drink
food
 => [nil, nil] 
1.9.3p392 :044 > jt=[]
 => [] 
1.9.3p392 :045 > m.global_tags.map { |t| jt << t.tag.phrase }
 => [["drink", "food"], ["drink", "food"]] 
1.9.3p392 :046 >
```

Also, I'm trying to get shorter syntax. This seems to work but not sure if this is considered ugly in Ruby terms(?)

```
1.9.3p392 :050 > m.global_tags.map(&:tag).map(&:phrase)
 => ["drink", "food"]
```

Thx for help

Comment: I don't think the latter is ugly, as long as you understand it and it doesn't get too convoluted it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You get two embedded arrays as the return value from `.map`, it's not `jt`. If you only need side-effects, use `.each`
2. This is bad performance-wise because you have to traverse the array two times.

`m.global_tags.map { |t| t.tag.phrase }` returns the result you want.

Comment: thx, yeah 1 is right - my mistake. Think I was trying to do something like your suggestion. have to wait like 10 min.

Comment: np - glad to know I helped anyway :)